# How to get the json response with the field name in struts2

Tags: jquery, json, hibernate, struts2

I have write the a json returning action in struts2 and it returns values successfully and i got the reponse as below

```
[[455,2,193,100.0,150],[459,1,193,45.0,67]]
```

But i need to get the response as {{`'id','455','inventory_id','2','doctor_id','193','price','100.0','credit','150'},{..}}`

like this. That is i want to return the json values with the curresponding field name so that i can iterate it easily. Anybody help me to implement that.

And i am using hibernate to access the database from the database.

This is my Action class

```
public class DoctorEcommerceWidgets extends ActionSupport {
    private String encryptId;
    private List<DoctorToProducts> listdoctorProducts;
    private int numberOfRowsPerPage;
    private int totalNumberOfRows;
    private int lastRows;
    private int pageNum;

    public String getEcommerceWidgetFour(){ 
        try{            
            Doctor DtObj = null;
            Map sessionSingleDoctor = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
            Object Obj = null;
            Obj = sessionSingleDoctor.get("Doctor");
            DtObj = (Doctor) Obj;
            int totalCount = DoctorDao.getInstance().totalNumberOfdoctorToProducts(DtObj.getId());
            numberOfRowsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(getText("ecommerce.widget.product.list.four"));
            totalNumberOfRows = (int)Math.ceil((float)totalCount/numberOfRowsPerPage);
            if(pageNum < 1){
                pageNum = 1;
            }else if(pageNum > lastRows){
                pageNum = lastRows;
            }
            listdoctorProducts = DoctorDao.getInstance().getDoctorProducts(DtObj.getId(),numberOfRowsPerPage,pageNum);



        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getEncryptId() {
        return encryptId;
    }

    public void setEncryptId(String encryptId) {
        this.encryptId = encryptId;
    }

    public List<DoctorToProducts> getListdoctorProducts() {
        return listdoctorProducts;
    }

    public void setListdoctorProducts(List<DoctorToProducts> listdoctorProducts) {
        this.listdoctorProducts = listdoctorProducts;
    }

    public int getLastRows() {
        return lastRows;
    }

    public void setLastRows(int lastRows) {
        this.lastRows = lastRows;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRowsPerPage() {
        return numberOfRowsPerPage;
    }

    public void setNumberOfRowsPerPage(int numberOfRowsPerPage) {
        this.numberOfRowsPerPage = numberOfRowsPerPage;
    }

    public int getTotalNumberOfRows() {
        return totalNumberOfRows;
    }

    public void setTotalNumberOfRows(int totalNumberOfRows) {
        this.totalNumberOfRows = totalNumberOfRows;
    } 

}
```

Comment: how you are creating/returning json data?

Comment: <action name="frPdtListPagination" class="com.zoondia.action.DoctorPdtsPagination" method="getEcommerceWidgetFourJson">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root" >listdoctorProducts</param>
                <param name="prettyPrint" >true</param>
            </result>
        </action>This is my action

Comment: i am assuming that you are using Struts2-Json plugin, can you show/update the post with your action class code

Comment: I am calling createQuery hibernate function to return the data from database and returning these values as list

Comment: I have updated the question with my action class

Comment: my original question is:how you converting data from `listdoctorProducts` to JSON?

Comment: No i am just use the <result type="json"></result> in my struts.xml. Nothing else i have written for changing the values to json. Is that you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8585/discussion-between-user359187-and-umesh-awasthi)

Comment: Sorry chat is not working for me..

Comment: are you using struts2-json plugin? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin

Comment: Yes i am using struts2-json plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
<param name="root" >listdoctorProducts</param>
<param name="prettyPrint" >true</param>
```

from struts.xml and you will figure it out

Look here:

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/json-plugin.html

Hope this helps